# They took an umbrella with them. It might rain. Connect these two sentences with the phrase in case

Tags: connected-speech

> They took an umbrella with them. It might rain.

Connect these two sentences with the phrase **in case**.

The right answer is:

> They took an umbrella with them **in case** it rained/ should rain.

Can you tell me why the following sentence is wrong and why the answer is right?

> They took an umbrella with them **in case** it might rain

Comment: You might find a previous question on this subject helpful: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/207447/what-tenses-should-be-used-after-in-case-of

Comment: But there is past tense. @RonaldSole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those questions whose answer might puzzle a great many native English speakers.

In everyday conversation people are as likely to use all three constructions - **rained, should rain and might rain** as well as **could rain** and **did rain** - not that I'm encouraging you to.

I can't find a clear explanation online of why the construction requires either **rained** or **should rain** and forbids **might rain**.

However, Google Books Ngram Viewer indicates that while **rained** and **should rain** have juggled for top position down the years, **rained** has become much more popular than **should rain** - while **might rain** has now virtually dropped out of usage.

A number of questions have been posted on online forums concerning the Verb tenses to follow **in case** and you might find the following links useful although they don't deal directly with your question:

[Usages of "in case" and "should" inversion](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44403/usages-of-in-case-and-should-inversion)
[usages of "in case" together with "should"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46638/usages-of-in-case-together-with-should)
https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/in-case-you-should-would.521437/

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+case+it+should+rain%2Cin+case+it+might+rain%2Cin+case+it+rained&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20case%20it%20should%20rain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20case%20it%20might%20rain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20case%20it%20rained%3B%2Cc0